# Tutorials on weka for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm a newbie in the field of Machine Learning, I would like to know if there are any tutorials on weka for Machine Learning.

Thanks,

Comment: did you search the weka site? I found many just by using google. http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index_documentation.html

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-weka1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link to the documentation is the obvious answer to your question, but the fact that you asked it leads me you believe you might have some misconceptions about the relationship between Machine Learning (ML) and datamining.

In essence, datamining algorithms are those that try and find the inherent structure in datasets, and Machine learning algorithms are those that improve their performance with increase data, so datamining is a proper subset of machine learning (specifically datamining=unsupervised ML with a bend toward database applications).

So since the whole of weka is a package of datamining algorithms, any documentation would be a machine learning tutorial.

If your looking for more general ML information, you must look outside of weka. I suggest Carnegie Mellon's [lecture notes on the subject](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~roni/10601-s10/).